# Currently using Thunderbird with Windows. Can I use the same Thunderbird after Ubuntu install (will remove windows)?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm currently using Thunderbird with Win XP and 7. I want to install Ubuntu on both computers (had enough of windows).

Question: will my current Thunderbird (that I am using with win) work with Ubuntu after I install it, or must I use a NEW Thunderbird install (I think it comes with Ubuntu package - therefore I must configure all my email accounts and loss mail history)? I will take out Win on both computers.

Answer (score 5):

Thunderbird works in Linux as you realise.  But you will need to migrate the data(you mail, address books, accounts etc over to Linux yourself.  The installation procedure will not do that for you. A Linux install will replace (or sit next to if dual booting) your windows install...they do not share data, in general, though some installers may copy data across.

Fortunately the data you need to move over is present in "[Profile Folders](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird)".  Locate this folder in your Windows install of Thunderbird and copy it into your [Thunderbird profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Linux_and_Unix) in your Linux install.  Confusingly this Profile directory is not the same as the profile directory in your Thunderbird Program folder. [Always back up first](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/profiles?s=back%20up&as=s#w_backing-up-a-profile).